# How to write a list of file names without file extension in ascending order into a text file?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to add to my batch script a command to sort the files in a directory with numbers in file name in ascending order. Then I want to write them all into a text file.

At the moment I managed to write the file names into a text file, but sorting is a problem. :(

```
for /R "C:\Users\AV\Desktop\AV_tests\Create_txt_file\" %%f in (*.jpg) do (
    echo %%~nf >> ROV_pics.txt
)
```

The numbers (file names with file extension) in the output file are:

```
13611821 
26811901 
15411801 
25812001 
15611461
```

How to get the file names (numbers) sorted in ascending order into the output file?

Comment: Just a note to say that Windows does not sort numerically, so if your number strings had for instance different amounts of characters you may not be happy with the results. e.g. given these: `67432784`, `7943676`, `472348`, they would sort in this order, `472348`,`67432784`, `7943676`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at *all* the options for the [`FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) command. In this case, you want the [`/F` option for processing the output of a command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html). You should also look at *all* the options for the [`DIR`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command. In this case, you will find the `/B` and `/O` options useful.

```
FOR /F %%I in ('dir /B /O:DN C:\Users\AV\Desktop\AV_tests\Create_txt_file\*.jpg') do echo %%~nI >> ROV_pics.txt
```

Note that if you have `usebackq` set, you should surround the `dir` command with backquotes instead of apostrophes; I have yet to figure out how to escape them when using them in SE-flavored MarkDown.

Comment: That was a great help! Thank you! :)

Comment: The space character between `%%~nI` and `>>` is also written into the output file as trailing space. Remove that space to get the numbers written without trailing space on each line into file `ROV_pics.txt`. I'm not sure why the ordering is done first on last modification date and second on file name (alphabetic and not numeric) by using `/O:DN` instead of `/O:N` or just `/ON` for a sort on file name only.

Comment: A `for /f` loop lossily decodes output from the pipe line-by-line using the console's current codepage, which defaults to OEM. Windows filesystems are UTF-16, so in general it is wrong to use a `for /f` loop unless a Unicode encoding is used, such as UTF-8. You can temporarily set the console codepage to UTF-8 via `chcp.com 65001`. First save the current codepage, and restore it after the loop. Add a note that the script should not be run detached (i.e. `DETACHED_PROCESS`), since Unicode won't be available; CMD hard codes using the ANSI codepage when it's not attached to a console.

Comment: @Mofi - `/O:DN` because I read something in the question that wasn't there; I thought the querent wanted the sort by date. You're correct; `/O:N` is sufficient, though there might be issues if the numeric file names have different lengths.

Comment: Hi!
I realized the /O:DN was not needed and changed to /O:N... the numeric file names will always have the same length as this script is already renaming these files before outputing to the text file. :)
It is working perfectly and already in production! Thank you all for the great help! :D